# Outlook replying to wrong email from Wordpress plugin Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, outlook, contact-form-7

I recently started working for a new company, which has a Wordpress website which uses the Contact Form 7 plugin. When we receive emails from the contact form and reply to them in Outlook, it automatically puts our own email address in the reply box (presumably from the "To" section of the form), instead of the email the person asking the question typed into the "From" section of the form.

What I'd like to happen is for Outlook to automatically insert the email from the "your email" section of the Contact 7 form into the "To" box in Outlook when I reply to an email. I'm not sure if this is a problem that could be fixed through the Contact Form 7 plugin, or a problem that could be fixed through Outlook.

I'm really sorry, I've never used Outlook or Wordpress before so I'm lost.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is a Q&A site for programming questions. Your question is about Wordpress administration and is thus off-topic on this site. For Wordpress, you can usually find help in the [Wordpress forum](https://wordpress.org/support/). Many plugins have a dedicated forum section where the developers of the plugin are happy to help you out. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Under Additional Headers in CF7, make sure you add: `Reply-To: [your-email]`, replacing `[your-email]` with whatever data-key you're collecting the email with.

Also note, `Reply-To:` is case-sensitive.

[Source / Credit](https://wpza.net/contact-form-7-emails-reply-to-wrong-email-address/)